# Image Segmentation U-Net model Assignment

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

**My U-Net model**

```
def unet_model(input_size=(96, 128, 3), n_filters=32, n_classes=23):

"""
Unet model

Arguments:
    input_size -- Input shape 
    n_filters -- Number of filters for the convolutional layers
    n_classes -- Number of output classes
Returns: 
    model -- tf.keras.Model
"""
inputs = Input(input_size)
# Contracting Path (encoding)
# Add a conv_block with the inputs of the unet_ model and n_filters
### START CODE HERE
cblock1 = conv_block(inputs, n_filters)
# Chain the first element of the output of each block to be the input of the next conv_block. 
# Double the number of filters at each new step
cblock2 = conv_block(cblock1[0], n_filters*2)
cblock3 = conv_block(cblock2[0], n_filters*4)
cblock4 = conv_block(cblock3[0], n_filters*8, dropout_prob=0.3) # Include a dropout_prob of 0.3 for this layer
# Include a dropout_prob of 0.3 for this layer, and avoid the max_pooling layer
cblock5 = conv_block(cblock4[0], n_filters*16, dropout_prob=0.3, max_pooling=False) 
### END CODE HERE

# Expanding Path (decoding)
# Add the first upsampling_block.
# Use the cblock5[0] as expansive_input and cblock4[1] as contractive_input and n_filters * 8
### START CODE HERE
ublock6 = upsampling_block(cblock5[0], cblock4[1],  n_filters*8)
# Chain the output of the previous block as expansive_input and the corresponding contractive block output.
# Note that you must use the second element of the contractive block i.e before the maxpooling layer. 
# At each step, use half the number of filters of the previous block 
ublock7 = upsampling_block(ublock6[0], cblock5[0],  n_filters*4)
ublock8 = upsampling_block(ublock7[0], ublock6[0],  n_filters*2)
ublock9 = upsampling_block(ublock8[0], ublock7[0],  n_filters)
### END CODE HERE

conv9 = Conv2D(n_filters,
             3,
             activation='relu',
             padding='same',
             kernel_initializer='he_normal')(ublock9)

# Add a Conv2D layer with n_classes filter, kernel size of 1 and a 'same' padding
### START CODE HERE
conv10 = Conv2D(n_filters, 1 , padding='same')(conv9)
### END CODE HERE

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

return model
```

...
In the Above Unet Model, the fisrt half of the model is completed i.e., upto cblock5
but from the second half of the model i.e., from cblock6 till cblock9 I got bit confused at
...

> # Chain the output of the previous block as expansive_input and the corresponding contractive block output.
> # Note that you must use the second element of the contractive block i.e before the maxpooling layer.
> # At each step, use half the number of filters of the previous block

...
Please help me with the above instruction meaning.
...

Comment: he is probably asking you to create residual blocks, and to create encoding and decoding blocks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The unet in the picture has 4 encoding block ( the descending one) and 4 decoding blocks.

in a unet the input of the decoding blocks (the ones where the tensor returns at the previous dimension) its the concatenation of the  block "at the same level" and the previous block, the assignment is asking you to do this concatenation ( you can see in the picture how 2 different arrows go in the decoding level, this are the 2 inputs)

`at each step use half the filters`: just use half the filters on each decoding level ( in the picture there are 4 decoding levels, so say you use N filters on the first decoding layer ( the one lower) you then use N/2 on the second decoding layer and so on)

`Note that you must use the second element of the contractive block i.e before the maxpooling layer.` : hard to tell, i think he is sayng that when you take the output of the encoder at level 3, at some point, you will want to give this input to the decoder at level 3 (the horizontal grey arrows in the figure, the input you need to concatenate), you need to take this input BEFORE the maxpooling, or it will not have the same dimensions (basically from an encoder there are 2 outputs, the red (maxpool) one and the grey (copy) one)

Answer (score 0):

here you go the problem was tracing the cblocks in the second half

```
# UNQ_C3
# GRADED FUNCTION: unet_model
def unet_model(input_size=(96, 128, 3), n_filters=32, n_classes=23):
    """
    Unet model
    
    Arguments:
        input_size -- Input shape 
        n_filters -- Number of filters for the convolutional layers
        n_classes -- Number of output classes
    Returns: 
        model -- tf.keras.Model
    """
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    # Contracting Path (encoding)
    # Add a conv_block with the inputs of the unet_ model and n_filters
    ### START CODE HERE
    cblock1 = conv_block(inputs, n_filters)
    # Chain the first element of the output of each block to be the input of the next conv_block. 
    # Double the number of filters at each new step
    cblock2 = conv_block(cblock1[0], 2*n_filters)
    cblock3 = conv_block(cblock2[0], 4*n_filters)
    cblock4 = conv_block(cblock3[0], 8*n_filters, dropout_prob=0.3) # Include a dropout_prob of 0.3 for this layer
    # Include a dropout_prob of 0.3 for this layer, and avoid the max_pooling layer
    cblock5 = conv_block(cblock4[0], 16*n_filters, dropout_prob=0.3, max_pooling=False) 
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    # Expanding Path (decoding)
    # Add the first upsampling_block.
    # Use the cblock5[0] as expansive_input and cblock4[1] as contractive_input and n_filters * 8
    ### START CODE HERE
    ublock6 = upsampling_block(cblock5[0], cblock4[1],  n_filters * 8)
    # Chain the output of the previous block as expansive_input and the corresponding contractive block output.
    # Note that you must use the second element of the contractive block i.e before the maxpooling layer. 
    # At each step, use half the number of filters of the previous block 
    ublock7 = upsampling_block(ublock6, cblock3[1],  n_filters * 4)
    ublock8 = upsampling_block(ublock7, cblock2[1],  n_filters * 2)
    ublock9 = upsampling_block(ublock8, cblock1[1],  n_filters*1)
    ### END CODE HERE

    conv9 = Conv2D(n_filters,
                 3,
                 activation='relu',
                 padding='same',
                 kernel_initializer='he_normal')(ublock9)

    # Add a Conv2D layer with n_classes filter, kernel size of 1 and a 'same' padding
    ### START CODE HERE
    conv10 = Conv2D(n_classes, 1, padding='same')(conv9)
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv10)

    return model
```

Comment: you saved me 